# php include on base of first folder in the path of url

Tags: php, include, directory

Is there a way to include a file on base of the first folder.
An example:

```
includes/file1.php
includes/file2.php
includes/file3.php
```

The folders on my site:

```
www.mysite.com/folder1
www.mysite.com/folder2
www.mysite.com/folder3
```

When I browse to www.mysite.com/folder1 it will include file1.php. When I browse to www.mysite/com/folder1/somExtraFolder/somethingElse it also will include file1.php.
When I go to www.mysite.com/folder2 it will include file2.php. When I browse to www.mysite/com/folder2/somExtraFolder/somethingElse it also will include file2.php and so on.

Is this possible in php or do I need to work with some kind of javascript/jquery to accomplish my goal.

Comment: What would javascript have to do with this at all?  You just need to set up your files appropriately.  It sounds like you may have need for implementing a `front controller` and/or `routing` strategy.  Google it.

Comment: Not JavaScript or jQuery.  If you are running apache and have access to the `php_value auto_prepend_file` you might specify a .htaccess file per directory in which you want to do the inclusion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Michael Berkowski has the correct answer, use PHP's [auto_prepend_file](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.auto-prepend-file)

You can set this setting per directory using .htaccess (Apache) or [.user.ini](http://www.php.net/manual/en/configuration.file.per-user.php) (CGI, FastCGI)

.htaccess style

```
php_value auto_prepend_file "file1.php"
```

.user.ini style

```
auto_prepend_file = "file1.php"
```

add the correct file type to the directory you want to modify (folder1, folder2, folder3) to have the auto_prepend_file automatically included, exactly as if you had used `require` or `include`, as the first script to run.

Comment: php_value auto_prepend_file "file1.php". doesn't it include the file in every page at the bottom? mady i needed to say that i want to have an include in a template file. for the menu. witch changes as when the user changes sub-directory.

Comment: @user3602420, it includes it at the top. If you wanted the content of file1.php, file2.php, or file3.php to render in a specific position, wrap it in a function, let's call it `renderMenu` and call that function in the correct place of your template.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a PHP question, this would be a function of your web server. Assuming Apache, you could use mod_rewrite and an .htaccess rule.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a router.

I'd highly recommend this one, I've used it before: http://toroweb.org/

You could then implement it like:

```
<?php

class File1 {
    function get() {
        include "file1.php";
    }
}

class File2 {
    function get() {
        include "file2.php";
    }
}

Toro::serve(array(
    "/includes/file1.php" => "File1",
    "/includes/file2.php" => "File2",
));
```

Comment: this sound's like it's someting i can use. only i have now idea of how this must work. i've lookt on the site and i don't know what type of script i need to use/make.

Comment: @user3602420 Basically what you need to do is make a class for each file and include it, then using the serve array set it up for each left half to be the way to access on the server and the right the class.